# Calculating the difference between two column with NULL's using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

Say I have a table say `student` with two nullable decimal columns like this

```
   A       B
-------|--------
   85  |  NULL
  NULL |  5
   50  |  30
```

I wish to calculate the difference between the sum of two columns A and B. i.e) `135 -  35= 100`

But with my current query i get  `(85 - NULL)  + (NULL - 5) + (50 - 30) = 0 - 0 + 20 = 20`

I'd write a SQL query like

```
select SUM(ISNULL(A, 0) - ISNULL(B, 0)) from student --100
```

But I'm not sure how this would be achievable in using EF

I currently write the below query which doesn't coalesce the null to zero.

```
var result = context.student.Sum(m=> m.A - m.B); // 20
```

I could use two separate `Sum`, but I prefer to write it in a single sum statement

```
var result = context.student.Sum(m=> m.A) - context.student.Sum(m=> m.B)
```

How do I achieve this using a single `Sum`

Comment: var result = context.student.Sum(m=> m.A ??0 - m.B ??0 );

Comment: @Luc: Might want to put parentheses on that, I suspect you're going to get `0 - m.B` when `m.A` is null.

Comment: @Flater you're right. That is why i though `??` might not be the solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [null coaliscing operator `??`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator).
If the part at it's left is null it return the right part:

```
int exemple = null ?? -1;
```

Here, with 0 as default value for null:

```
var result = context.student.Sum(m=> (m.A??0) - (m.B??0));
```